# Telling the caller of a function 'nicely' that a promise can't be met

Tags: javascript, winjs, promise

This is my async search function.

```
function searchAsync(searchText) {
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete) {
        if (searchText.length > 2) {
            // Asynchronously query the API with the search text
        } else {
            // Can't return a promise, since 'searchText' is too short
        }
    });
}
```

Assuming that the caller doesn't provide a `searchText` with more than 2 characters, how can I tell him that he has to provide a longer search text?

I could return `null`... But as the caller expects a promise I'd rather want to tell him that no promise can be given.

Comment: just fulfill the promise right away with an error action.

Comment: @dan, my apologies for the duplicate comment, I failed to parse `fulfill ... with an error action`. I'll keep the link to [wrapError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229784.aspx) and remove the rest.

Comment: well, when things are good you give a promise back. can't you handle the error in the function that launches the search, calling the 2nd argument to invoke the error handler?

Comment: You can only do three things with a deferred/promise, (1) nothing (allow it to remain "pending"), (2) resolve it, (3) reject it. "Niceness" (if it exists) is determined not by the change of the promise's state itself but by the actions taken by any `.then()` etc. handlers invoked on the promise.

Comment: Correct terminology is that a promise can be "fulfilled" or "rejected", either of which is referred to as it being "resolved". It would be useful to avoid potentially confusing expressions such as "fulfill with an error action" or say "resolve" when you mean "fulfill".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an error handler and call it when the Promise would be in an error state.

```
function searchAsync(searchText) {
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete, error) {
        if (searchText.length > 2) {
            // Asynchronously query the API with the search text
            complete(results);
        } else {
            // Can't return a promise, since 'searchText' is too short
            error();
        }
    });
}
```